# Switching on DC to AC converter large voltage drop

Tags: inverter, converter, voltage, dc-ac

[![Current pulse at source of PMOS][1]][1][![Test across inductor with 470ohm at gate of PMOS][2]][2]I am trying to switch on a DC to AC converter, the load for the primary side of the circuit (where the DMM is measuring across) is a transformer (which I have unfortunately not picked out yet due to being unable to produce a working DC to AC converter, and as a note the only concern for frequency and current I have is to make sure components aren't getting too hot, or damaged, also, ideally I would like a transformer on the scale of 5 inches and under which usually means higher frequency, aside from that frequency and current can vary) and I am trying to step up voltage to upwards of around 390VDC which will be delivered to the load which in my case is a cathode to create the electric field. I just want to create an electric field at the load of the secondary side of the circuit to achieve phase transition in Bose-Einstein Condensate by increasing the voltage instead of lowering the temperature. The rectifier portion seems to be working well (tested separately with AC voltage applied) but I am having trouble with the DC to AC converter portion. The switching event works as expected which means I have approximately 12VDC going into my LM555. However when I measure after the DC to AC converter there's a result of <1VAC. Am I doing something wrong here circuit wise or the way I am measuring? Why such the large voltage drop? R1 = 10kohm, R2 = 100kohm, R3 = 100kohm (initially).
[image]

Comment: What transistor part number are you using for the output PMOS?

Comment: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/FQP47P06-1009447.pdf

Comment: Please use username tags when you reply to specifically someone's question. Like *@ThePhoton mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/FQP47P06-1009447.pdf*.

Comment: Oh okay I didn't know, thank you! @RohatKılıç

Comment: Your DMM - what frequency response has it got for AC signals and, what frequency does your 555 operate at?

Comment: @Andyaka the 555 is at around 1.5kHz, but I am unsure about what the DMM can handle it is a benchtop DMM not a handheld. I was told they usually lose accuracy at around 1kHz, is it different for different DMM's?

Comment: @Andyaka I will when I have access to it, it is not at my house. I guess that's something that would just be on the spec sheet right?

Comment: In electronics engineering, the electronics is the relatively easy part, it's the engineering that gives all the problems and complications. "the current on the secondary side as well as the frequency isn't really important" - yes it is :-) Please don't add only what you think is important. That edit is a long way short. Nothing about the transformer or its load or the final application, all of which is very relevant to answering the question, far more relevant than what you've added.

Comment: @TonyM okay I edited it again. I tried to be as specific as I can. Hopefully its a little clearer on what I need and why and everything, thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

A push-pull output such as your NE555's is ideal for driving the gate. However, your 100K gate series resistor (R3) is far too high. That resistor has to charge the gate-drain capacitance of your FQP47P06 output MOSFET.

From its datasheet, that's Ciss which is 2800 pF typ. and 3600 pF max. Working from the max. value, a very rough calculation shows it taking over 400 us to charge your MOSFET gate capacitance from the NE555 low output voltage of 0.1 V to the 2.6 V or so Vgs needed to start turning on the MOSFET.

Your 1.5 kHz output has a period of around 666 us. So the rise time and fall time of the MOSFET gate signal are much longer than the waveform period and it never sees a square wave.

Reducing the gate resistor (R3) to 470R gives, very roughly, a rise time of around 2 us. The fall time will be of a similar order, so the combined rise/fall time should be <10 us, less than 2% of the gate waveform period.

The gate resistor must be large enough for the MOSFET gate current at switching to not exceed the NE555 max. output current of 200 mA. The 470R on a 12 V output will draw around  25 mA instantaneous current as a very brief spike. To ensure this current spike does not cause an NE555 supply rail dip, you should put a decoupling capacitors across its supply rail and ground, close to the NE555 +Vcc and GND pins. Use both a 10 uF and a 100 nF in parallel.

Comment: @jim0000, have you tried changing R3 to 470R as I described?

Comment: I am unable to physically test it at the moment, but I am able to run a simulation with the change. I am confused by where you mean to put the two decoupling capacitors. Also, do I even need the PMOS to generate the AC signal or could I just use the LM555? I edited my original post to show a simulation with 470ohms at the gate of the PMOS. I measured across an inductor since it wouldn't let me measure voltage across to points with them being open ended and because I will be using an inductor there. I also added a measurement to measure the current pulse at the source of the PMOS.

Comment: @jim0000, Google 'decoupling capacitors' if you don't know what they are. But they go across the NE555 supply pins, as my answer now describes better, to stabilise it. The benefit of them probably won't show up on your simulation because it doesn't have got the wires between the two boards/boxes the real one has. Aside from that, what's the load on your MOSFET - is it a transformer or something? You realise you'll get chopped DC out of your MOSFET circuit, rather than AC which cycles its polarity back and forth?

Comment: yes its a transformer, I haven't had a lot of experience with decoupling capacitors but I do have a sense of their purpose. Will a transformer as the load not work with how I am trying to produce AC signal then?

Comment: @jim0000, depends what you're trying to do and your question doesn't explain your application at all: what you're building, why, what it's for, what you're trying to power and so on. Please first edit that into your question, don't post it in comments. Plenty of explanation and detail. Don't just throw a couple of sentences in or put it off "til later when I've time". The better your question quality, the better the quality of the answers it attracts. Is it school project? Btw, you'll sometime need an oscilloscope to get it working properly - simulation and DMM won't cut it. Got access to one?

Comment: okay I edited my post but I will highlight it here, essentially I want to step the voltage up to around 300V using a transformer, from there it gets rectified back to DC voltage. The rectifier works fine, but I am having trouble with producing the AC signal on the primary side of the transformer. I do have access to an oscilloscope thankfully. It is for a group I am in so its not really a school project.

Answer (score 0):

The gate-stopper resistor and the C<sub>gd</sub> of the MOSFET form a first-order LPF, which may chop-off the gate drive signals:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCFJlx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In your circuit, the gate stopper resistor (R3) is way too high. And if the frequency is high enough *(we don't know since C2 is unknown, but I assume it's in the kHz range)* you can never drive that MOSFET. Also, if you are measuring with a DMM, you can't expect it to measure the high frequencies correctly *(Most DMMs can measure good up to around 1kHz)*.

Here's a better way of having the 12V-pulsed output:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6UwxS.png)</sup>

With the circuit above, the load is kept grounded and you can get the full 12V swing. Remember that the DMM still may not be able to measure the voltage correctly if the frequency is high enough.

Comment: Oh okay thank you I am around 1.5kHz, would that be too high of a frequency to measure with a DMM? Also, I was curious if I even needed the PMOS to generate the 12V swing? If I do need it, I see that you implemented an BJT npn at the gate, would it be operating like a switch then?

Comment: I meant to make the above comment as a reply I wasn't sure how to tag people, thanks for the insight! @RohatKılıç

Comment: @jim0000 1.5kHz should be acceptable for the DMM. In your original circuit, you were trying to switch the negative rail with PMOS; this may not be that effective. With my approach, the PMOS acts as a switch, and the BJT is required to drive it fully *(Look at the SWITCH block in the original circuit. There's nearly nothing different)*. Plus, you will be able to measure the output directly with the DMM.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, so the PMOS should act as a switch then? Why is that needed to generate AC signal? I am curious about it's purpose in the DC to AC converter. If it is needed could I make it to where it was always fully on if the 1st switch is on? Or would that change anything?